# How big can a commutative algebra of $n \times n$ matrices be?

Tags: matrices

What's the maximum possible dimension of a commutative subalgebra of the algebra of $n \times n$ complex matrices?

There's a theorem of Burnside saying that any commutative subalgebra of a matrix algebra can be upper triangularized.  My friend Bruce Smith pointed out that for $n$ even we can get a commutative subalgebra of dimension $(\frac{n}{2})^2 + 1$.  For $n = 4$ its elements look like this:

$$\left( \begin{array}{cccc}
a & 0 & b & c \\
0 & a & d & e \\
0 & 0 & a & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a 
\end{array}\right)$$

and the same trick works in any even dimension.  For $n$ odd we can get dimension $\frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{2} + 1$ using a similar idea, with a rectangle rather than a square of nonzero entries in the upper right corner.

Can one do better?  Someone must have figured this out.

Comment: In particular, Robin's answer there confirms your conjecture.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, Christian Remling!  There's a [much harder question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29087/commutative-subalgebras-of-m-n) to which Robin Chapman gave an answer to my question here.

In short: Bruce's guess is indeed the best we can do.  This fact was proved by Schur, and there's also a proof here:

- Maryam Mirzakhani, [A simple proof of a theorem of Schur](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/mirzakhani.pdf), *Amer. Math. Monthly* **105** (1998), 260–262.